# Solve $2^x+y^2=z!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Determine $x,y,z$, where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $2^x+y^2=z!\,$.

I found out that $(0,0,1),(0,1,2),(1,0,2),(1,2,3),(3,4,4)$ are solutions.
 I think that for $z \geq5$ there isn't any other solution, but I don't know how to prove this for larger numbers.
 I've tried proving it with "the last digit trick", since we know that for any  $z \geq5$, $z!$ ends in $0$, but this didn't work for me. And, obviously, $y$ has to be even.

Comment: $z!$ is even so $y$ must be even

Comment: @MyGlasses     Except  for 1!....

Comment: I've already written that y is even, except for the $(0,1,2)$ solution. :)

Comment: what about modular arithmetic on the values below z.

Comment: This might help, at least when $x$ is even: http://oeis.org/A001481

Comment: Hint: look modulo $7$.

Comment: It's more rigorous to notate that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are natural numbers as $$(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{N}^3$$ especially if you reference ordered triples later ;)

Comment: Even better look at mod $5$ since $y$ is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try factoring $z! = 2^{\alpha_0} 3^{\alpha_1} 5^{\alpha_2} \ldots {p_n}^{\alpha_n}$, where $p_1$ through $p_n$ are the first $n$ odd primes. Then $z! - 2^x = 2^x m$. We know that $\gcd(3^{\alpha_1} 5^{\alpha_2} \ldots {p_n}^{\alpha_n}, m) = 1$, because $\gcd(2^x, 3^{\alpha_1} 5^{\alpha_2} \ldots {p_n}^{\alpha_n}) = 1$ as well.

Okay, sorry, that's not as fruitful as I thought it would be, so I'm just going to elaborate on Wowoju's hint.

Clearly, $z! \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ for all $z > 6$. And $2^x \equiv 1, 2, 4 \pmod 7$. So $z! - 2^x \equiv 6, 5, 3 \pmod 7$. But those are precisely the impossible squares modulo 7.

Now all you have to do is go case-by-case $0 < z < 7$ to check if you have already found all possible solutions.